# Get substring form an integer column

Tags: postgresql, integer, substring

I had a quick question, how can I go about using SUBSTRING on an integer? I currently have field labeled "StoreID" that contains a 5 digit integer (60008). I am trying to use SUBSTRING to remove the 6 when I query out this information. When I use something like:

`SUBSTRING('StoreID', 2, 6)`
I get an error returning back saying that `SUBSTRING(integer,integer,integer)` does not exist.

Is there another function I can use in postgres to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast the integer

```
SUBSTR(cast (StoreId as text), 2,6)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are interested in the *number* **`8`**, use the [modulo operator `%`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-math.html)

```
SELECT 60008%10000
```

If you want the  *string* **`'0008'`**, the function [`right()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is  right for you (added with Postgres 9.1):

```
SELECT right(60008::text, -1)
```

Or with modulo and [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE):

```
SELECT to_char(60008%10000, 'FM0000')
```

The `FM` modifier removes space padding.